# How to use $ symbol before an EL expression?

Tags: jsp, el

I need to print $10
 my code is

```
  $${valueBean.price}
  but it gives value as  $${valueBean.price}
```

How can i ignore EL expression for this case.

Comment: "$ ${valueBean.price}" works I guess

Comment: Yes $ ${valueBean.price}" works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Html Entity for Dollar sign:

```
&#36;
```